# How can I reliably defeat Spade?

Tags: freedom-planet

Playing Freedom Planet, most of the bosses have several complicated attack patterns that you have to learn how to respond to. Once you've figured out their patterns, you can reliably dodge their attacks and damage them.

I can beat most bosses relatively comfortably, but I haven't figured out how to deal with Spade's patterns. I have a few problems:

- Spade moves very quickly, often jumping more than an entire screen's width within about a second. This makes it difficult to track him down to damage him.
- When Spade lands next to me to throw cards, it's difficult to predict whether he'll land on my right or my left, again making it difficult to counterattack.
- When I try to chase Spade down, I find it very difficult to dodge his projectiles, which are fast and typically land right where I'm running to.
- As Lilac, I can hide on the ledge above the boss arena to take cheap shots (and heal on easier difficulties). Since I'm in a different arena, this isn't possible with Carol or Milla. Likewise, Carol can use the jump pads in the arena to move around quickly, but Milla can't.

What are some strategies for beating Spade? Is there a single strategy that works for all three characters, or do they all have different strategies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spade is designed to punish aggressive play. There isn't any foolproof stategy, since he likes to mix up his pattern a bit, but the general flowchart is as follows:

- Wait for him to appoach you.
- He will stop in front on you and throw his cards from the ground.
  Jump over them.
- Hit him now. Regular punches, Divekicks and Boost work the best
- Now he will do some airdashes and will try to attack from air.
- It's possible to hit him there, but your best bet is to simply avoid
  him. Keep some speed and avoid this attack by moving away or under
  him (away is preferable)
- Pattern repeats.

He will mostly still to Ground Attack -> Air Attack -> Ground Attack -> (...). Punish him on ground attacks.

The strategy works for other characters, but Carol has a harder time fighting him because of jump height and slower speed. Use sidewalls for your advantage.

Comment: I finally got around to trying the strategy you suggested, and it worked great! Thank you =)